# Errors trying to install the driver for ASUS USB-AC51 AC600

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, compiling, asus

I just bought a wireless adapter USB from ASUS. It's called ASUS USB-AC51 (Wireless-AC600).
I've installed the drivers from https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/USB-AC51/DR_USB_AC51_V1013.zip .

I extracted the .tar file, went to Linux folder, extracted again and after following "Quick Start DPO.txt" I just blocked at some point. When I ran Makefile with "make", I got an error which is fixed by changing SUBDIRS with M (I saw this on a forum). This error got fixed.

After this I started to get errors for files. The "make" command was trying to search ".o" files. I went to these directiories and saw the name of the files, but with ".c", so I just renamed them from ".c" to ".o".

Now, I've got to a point where the program is searching for "mt7650u_sta.o" in /os/linux/, but that file is not there. As well, it doesn't recognize a file I changed from ".c" to ".o", more exactly "sta_cfg.o" from /os/linux/.

The error looks like this:

```
/home/hakju/Documents/AC51/ASUS_USB-AC51_V1.0.1.3_09212015/Linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3001_dpo_20130725/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:440: /home/hakju/Documents/AC51/ASUS_USB-AC51_V1.0.1.3_09212015/Linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3001_dpo_20130725/os/linux/mt7650u_sta.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/hakju/Documents/AC51/ASUS_USB-AC51_V1.0.1.3_09212015/Linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3001_dpo_20130725/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:394: LINUX] Error 2
```

What should I do?

I have Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-40-generic.
lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0b05:17d1 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AC51 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Mediatek MT7610U]
```

modinfo mt76x0u | grep 17D1:

```
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

sudo dmesg | grep mt7: https://pastebin.com/jnnB75Pu (is too long to be added here)

Comment: Please edit your post to show the result of the terminal command: `modinfo mt76x0u | grep 17D1` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7` That circa-2015 file will never compile on any modern kernel version. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Done. The second command was too long so I added a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options mt76-usb disable_usb_sg=Y" > /etc/modprobe.d/mt76-usb.conf
exit
```

Reboot and show us again:

```
sudo dmesg | grep mt7
```

Comment: The command "sudo dmesg | grep mt7 " doesn't show anything after reboot.

Comment: Did the module load? `lsmod | grep mt7` If not, load it: `sudo modprobe  mt76x0u` Any errors or warnings? Check again: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7`

Comment: ```lsmod | grep mt7``` doesn't show anything.
After ```sudo modprobe  mt76x0u``` and ```sudo dmesg | grep mt7``` I've got ```[28904.362889] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt76x0u
```

Comment: and ```lsmod | grep mt7``` is now loading https://pastebin.com/aig47hmf .

Comment: *iwlwifi* ?? Do you have an internal wireless device that's not working as expected? I'd expect an internal device to outperform a USB always.

Comment: I guess I do have an internal wireless device because I use wireless internet from router. I'm using a laptop. I don't know if the wireless device works or not as expected. The reason I'm using an USB is to see if I can solve the problem of bad internet. For some reason, my internet got really bad and interrupts all the time.
iwlwifi doesn't show anything. (I'm using Ubuntu for a short time, so I don't really know the commands and stuff yet)

Comment: I suggest that we troubleshoot the internal dropouts first. I believe it is easily fixable. Please start a new question. Please include the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list`